# iphone uitableview data limits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

How much data we can load in uitableview, is it possible to load more than 10,000 data in table view cell..?

What is the data limit in uitableView..?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableView is just view that displays your data so it absolutely doesn't care about how many data you want to render. It is designed to effectively render only the visible cells. So the best choice for you is to load data lazily (when it is needed to be displayed). If you have more then 10000 records, than it's probably good idea to preload only small amount of data (say 100 records) into memory from file and feed the table view with that data.

Answer (score 2):

You can load as much data as the iPhone's ram, and your algorithms can handle.

Answer (score 0):

@nivas what's this data limit in `UITableView` exactly means....It depends on you and the size of your UITableView cell that what size you had given to your UITableView (you have to customize its size) and its cell.you can give give as much data you can but that that much data will not be more that the memory limit of your iPhone..